How to determine the maximum value of an array in cplex opl?
I want to find the maximum value of an array in cplex opl.
For example:
 forall(i in hour){
  S_total[i]==sqrt((P_tload[i]+P_EV[i])^2+Q_tload[i]^2);   
 }

In the above example, I want to find Smax, which is equal to the maximum value of the array S_total. Here, P_EV[i] is a variable.

You can use "max" as can be seen in the example https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoomax.mod
maxNbOfBusesGivenSize==max(i in buses) nbBus[i];

in
int nbKids=300;

{int} buses={30,40,50};


dvar int+ nbBus[buses];
dvar int maxNbOfBusesGivenSize;

    
minimize maxNbOfBusesGivenSize;
     
subject to
{
 // logical constraint
 // maxNbOfBusesGivenSize is the max of all nbBus
 maxNbOfBusesGivenSize==max(i in buses) nbBus[i];
 sum(i in buses) i*nbBus[i]>=nbKids;
}

execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
{
  writeln("The max number of buses is ",maxNbOfBusesGivenSize);
  writeln("nbBus = ",nbBus);
}

